# Calculating $Y|X$ density with distribution $U[X,X+1]$

Tags: probability, probability-theory

I have two random variables $X$ and $Y$ where $X$ has distribution $U [0; 1]$ and $Y | X$ has distribution $U [X; X +1]$ (that is, $f (x) = 1$ for $x$ and $[0, 1]$ and $0$ cc, and $fY|X(y|x) = 1$ if $y \in[x; x + 1]$ and $0$ cc, for all $x$.)

How can I calculate the density of Y?

Also, can you clarify how to work with $U [X; X +1]$?

Any hint?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given the marginal distribution for $X$, and the conditional distribution $Y|X$, you can recover the distribution for $Y$ from a continuous version of the law of total probability:
$$
f_Y(y) = \int f_{Y|X=x}(y)f_X(x)\,dx
$$
The marginal pdf $f_X(x)$ is $1$ on $[0,1]$ and $0$ elsewhere, so this becomes
$$
f_Y(y)=\int_0^1 f_{Y|X=x}(y)\,dx
$$
The conditional pdf $f_{Y|X=x}(y)$ is equal to $1$ when $x<y<x+1$. Otherwise, it is $0$. Effectively, in addition to the bounds $0<x<1$ of integration, we also have the bounds $y-1<x<y$. These two imply we are integrating the function $1$ over the region where $\max(0,y-1)<x<\min(1,y)$. Whenever $0<y<2$, this region is nonempty, and we get
$$
f_Y(y)=\int_{\max(0,y-1)}^{\min(1,y)}1\,dx=\min(1,y)-\max(0,y-1).
$$
When $0<y<1$, $f_Y(y)=y$. When $1<y<2$, $f_Y(y)=2-y$. Otherwise, $f_Y(y)=0$.

Comment: thank you very much. Its really difficult this question for  me. Thanks!